# Python ElementClickInterceptedException in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on a selenium based python automation project. The code automates some regular tasks by connecting to the company's internal webpage url. However, the code occasionally throws the same exception between two button click actions. Could you please help me to figure out what's the point that I miss? Thanks in advance.
You can find my code snippet and error screenshot here:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message:
>   element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (180,
>   447). Other element would receive the click: ...

[pycharm_error_output_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AccVU.jpg)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

timeout = 200
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

driver.get("https://internal_web_appplication_page_for_company_x")

apply_button_v4 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//body//button[2]")))
apply_button_v4.click()
both_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "// label[3] // span[1]")))
wait.until_not(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "map-mask")))
wait.until_not(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "// *[ contains( @ class, 'map-mask')]")))
both_button.click()
```

The intercepted element is full screen "loading" notification which is visible for a short period of time following any click action.
Moreover, my code works as expected if i put **time.sleep(5)** before clicking "both_button".

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution for clicking on both_button. There are multiple reasons of this exception like javascript or ajax call , element is not in the view port.

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(both_button)
actions.click(both_button)
actions.perform()
```

Comment: Just tried the solution but nothing happens after running the code. The code snippet runs without any exceptions/errors but "both_button" is not clicked.
Moreover, my original code works as expected if i put time.sleep(5) before clicking "both_button".

Comment: Can you please share url ? I will check from my end.

Comment: Unfortunately it's an internal application. That's why you can only access through the company's vpn application and credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just tried to make sure if it helps. But unfortunately the problem still persists. Actually i don't face any timeout exception. That's why timeout increase will not work even if i set it to the maximum. The problem is the intermediate "loading" splash screen between two button click actions. Selenium attempts to click before waiting "loading" splash screen to disappear. My "wait until" code section does not really wait what it is supposed to wait. I don't know why.